# Update Data from another table with more conditions PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

So I have this following table
**Table 1**

| NIP | NAMA_PENSIUN | JNS_KELAMIN | ID_PTKP | NPWP_PENSIUN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 195605212010002 | Hardjadi | Laki-Laki | K3 | 939766245522000 |
| 195402192010003 | Sutikno | Laki-Laki | K1 | 937896346533000 |
| 196008142010004 | Adlina Humaira | Perempuan | TK0 | 937686259522000 |
| 196401012010005 | Retno Subandi | Laki-Laki | TK2 | 917678275532000 |
| 195908302010006 | Baby Fajrina | Perempuan | K3 | 982638279888000 |

**Table 2**

| ID_PTKP | KET_PTKP | TARIF_PTKP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TK0 | Tidak Kawin - 0 Tanggungan | 54,000,000 |
| TK1 | Tidak Kawin - 1 Tanggungan | 58,500,000 |
| TK2 | Tidak Kawin - 2 Tanggungan | 63,000,000 |
| TK3 | Tidak Kawin - 3 Tanggungan | 67,500,000 |

**Table 3**

| TAHUN_PAJAK | NPWP_PENSIUN | PENGHSL_PENSIUN | NILAI_PTKP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 939766245522000 | 7500000 |  |
| 2021 | 937896346533000 | 4500000 |  |
| 2021 | 937686259522000 | 4000000 |  |

I want to update NILAI_PTKP in the **table 3** from TARIF_PTKP **table 2**, but table 3 has the same identifier which is NPWP_PENSIUN with table 1, and table 1 has the same identifier from table 2 which is ID_PTKP. from this what syntax I should use?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I have edited it

Comment: Is `"table 3".nilai_ptkp` supposed to always have the same value like the corresponding `"table 2".tarif_ptkp`, i.e. if `"table 2".tarif_ptkp` changes, should `"table 2".tarif_ptkp` change too `"table 3".nilai_ptkp`?

Comment: Also [edit] the question and show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Comment: If you found a solution for your question, post it as *answer*, not in the question. You can then also accept it.

Answer (score 0):

`merge` is one option:

```
SQL> merge into table3 c
  2    using (select a.npwp_pensiun, b.tarif_ptkp
  3           from table1 a join table2 b on a.id_ptkp = b.id_ptkp
  4          ) x
  5    on (c.npwp_pensiun = x.npwp_pensiun)
  6    when matched then update set
  7      c.nilai_ptkp = x.tarif_ptkp;

1 row merged.

SQL> select * From table3;

      NPWP_PENSIUN NILAI_PTKP
------------------ ----------
   939766245522000
   937896346533000
   937686259522000   54000000

SQL>
```

Why is only one row updated? Because sample data you posted doesn't have match between `table1` and `table2`.

Comment: Table1 and Table2 have ID_PTKP that matched

Comment: Anyway thanks for your kind answer, I already solve the problem myself

Comment: Exactly, there are values that match and the only row that can be joined has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Already solve with

```
UPDATE (SELECT pt.NILAI_PTKP A, tp.TARIF_PTKP B FROM PajakTahunan pt  
JOIN MasterPensiun mp ON pt.NPWP_PENSIUN = mp.NPWP_PENSIUN
JOIN TarifPTKP tp ON mp.ID_PTKP = tp.ID_PTKP)
SET A = B;
```

Comment: In Oracle updatable subquery have a lot of limitations, so this answer have nearly no value without actual tables' definitions.